# c++ enum class inside std::multimap

Tags: c++, c++11

I'm having 2 `enum`s which are of the newer enum class type.

```
enum class Action
{
    Move,
    Attack,
    Die,
    Splash,
    Idle
};

enum class Facing
{
    Left,
    LeftUp,
    LeftDown,
    Up,
    Down,
    Right,
    RightUp,
    RightDown
};
```

And I want to store this stuff inside a multimap:

```
std::multimap<Entity::Facing,std::pair<Entity::Action,std::unique_ptr<Animation>>> listAnimation;
```

The key is: facing and the pair is the action of the entity + the animation.

This is how i insert it:

```
std::unique_ptr<Animation> splashUp (new Animation());
splashUp->setSpriteSheet(*texture);
splashUp->addFrame(sf::IntRect(3584,256,128,128));
splashUp->addFrame(sf::IntRect(3712,256,128,128));
splashUp->addFrame(sf::IntRect(3840,256,128,128));
splashUp->addFrame(sf::IntRect(3968,256,128,128));
splashUp->addFrame(sf::IntRect(4096,256,128,128));
splashUp->addFrame(sf::IntRect(4224,256,128,128));
splashUp->addFrame(sf::IntRect(4352,256,128,128));
splashUp->addFrame(sf::IntRect(4480,256,128,128));

this->listAnimation.insert(Entity::Facing::Up, std::make_pair(Entity::Action::Splash, std::move(splashUp)));
```

and this is the error which I can't wrap my head around even after alot of googling:

> error C2664: 'std::_Tree_iterator<_Mytree>
>   std::multimap<_Kty,_Ty>::insert(std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>,const
>   std::pair<_Ty1,_Ty2> &)' : cannot convert parameter 1 from
>   'Entity::Facing' to 'std::_Tree_const_iterator<_Mytree>' 1>
>   with 1>          [ 1>
>   _Mytree=std::_Tree_val>>>>,
>   1>              _Kty=Entity::Facing, 1>
>   _Ty=std::pair>, 1>              _Ty1=const Entity::Facing, 1>              _Ty2=std::pair> 1>          ] 1>          and 1>          [ 1>
>   _Mytree=std::_Tree_val>>>>
>   1>          ] 1>          No user-defined-conversion operator
>   available that can perform this conversion, or the operator cannot be
>   called

Can I use enum class as Key in multimap at all?

Comment: which `insert` overload allows you to do what you want? Read documentation and check how `insert` works.

Comment: You may use a [`std::unordered_multimap`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/unordered_multimap). `std::multimap` requires a definition of the `std::less()` comparator for the key type.

Comment: @πάντα ῥεῖ yes that was the container i was looking for. Trying to figure out how to implement a hash now for my enum class. Cheers mate

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you check the [docs for `multimap::insert`](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/map/multimap/insert/), you can see that there is no method with a signature that matches what you're trying to do. The methods are:

> single element (1) `iterator insert (const value_type& val);` with hint (2)   `iterator insert (iterator position, const value_type& val); range (3)`
>   template  void insert (InputIterator first, InputIterator last);`

You are attempting to insert a value into the object, i.e. (1), but the compiler is confused, as the function arity makes it look like the latter 2.

For inserting a value, you need to create a pair, i.e., `insert(make_pair(...))`. As a special case, each data is mapped in your case to a pair as well, so it will end up being `insert(make_pair(..., make_pair(...)))`.

In any case, there is no `insert` that takes a key and a mapping as two parameters, as you are trying to do.

Answer (score 1):

[`multimap<Key, Value>::insert()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/insert) takes only one parameter, which should be convertible to `std::pair<const Key, Value>`.

For convenience, and possibly for some speedup (because you don't have to create a temporary `pair`), you can use [`emplace()`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/multimap/emplace) instead:

```
listAnimation.emplace(Entity::Facing::Up, std::make_pair(Entity::Action::Splash, std::move(splashUp)));
```